# Why chrome reports "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: n is not a function"?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I wrote some javascript in .net core by visual studio 2019. And after it runs in chrome(version 70.0.3538.110). Chrome reports this error: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: n is not a function
It is so strange that all the javascript runs well, but it still reports this.
What's more, when I click into the error, it displays a blank page as the image shows below.
In addition, it is so strange that the errors sometimes occur and sometimes do not by chrome.
What's wrong with it? How can I solve this problem? Although it will not affect the program runs, I want to clear it. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like n is not a function. Click the little `{}` button and see if the code loads. My guess is you have a memory issue and chrome is not loading the code into the editor (clear the cache and see if it fixes it)

Comment: I do not use a function which named n in the js. However, I used the js/css minification which provides by Microsoft in .net core . I wonder if is the problem of the js/css minification.@epascarello

Comment: Yes, it is minimized so you have single letter variables. Impossible for us to guess from an image with no code what the issue actually is. Normally a .map file makes it better.

Comment: Emmmm, it seems I can only report this to Microsoft?@epascarello

Comment: more like you have a bug in your code, run your build so it is not minimized and than you can see the error.

Comment: @epascarello Well, I ran the code which is not minimized several times but all ran well. What's more, the minimized code some time throws the error but not always even I tried all JS event in the page.

Comment: @epascarello I just considered for a long time, I think the js code maybe has no error for the Visual Studio reports no error yet.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some Chrome's extentions lead to this problem. try your code in incognito mode.